# Cannot compile mono with cross compiler

Tags: arm, mono, embedded-linux, cross-compiling, monodevelop

I am attempting to cross compile mono 6.12 to 32bit arm platform.  It gets through a chunk of compilation, but then fails on the Metadata abi.c file on an enum which includes object-offsets.h.  Apparently it thinks nothing is presented by the object-offsets.h file and the enum is empty, an illegal condition.  I checked the config.h file and target-arm is defined and mono_offsets_file is undefined so not sure what is killing the info this .h file is to present.  Am I missing some configure parameter?

Comment: While it might still be a valid question here, you should think twice whether to make use of such a project on the verge of deprecation, https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/

Comment: Yes, I see .net 6 targeted for other platforms but is it size scalable for custom embedded systems and compatible with ARMv7-M